# Creating custom contentView with card

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

What's the best way to create a custom content view with the card? Right now I do this:

```
    fileprivate var contentView: View!
    fileprivate func prepareContentView() {
    contentView = View()

    let button = RaisedButton(title: "Raised Button", titleColor: .white)
    button.pulseColor = .white
    button.backgroundColor = Color.blue.base
    contentView.layout(button)
        .width(150)
        .height(44)
        .center()
    }
```

And then when assigning my content view to the card:

```
card.contentView = contentView
card.contentViewEdgeInsetsPreset = .wideRectangle3
```

However the content view does not show up.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `contentView` has a frame of `.zero` when trying to set the constraints. That said you can set the size of your `contentView` and all should work:

```
contentView = View(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 44))
```

All the best!